# variable declaration problem

Tags: variables, pointers, constants, declaration

Explain the difference between how variables p and q are declared. Describe when you would use one declaration and when you would use the other.

```
int x = 5;

const int *p = &x;

int * const q = &x;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 5;
const int *p = &x;
```

This assigns the address of `x` to the *pointer to const int* `p`. That means the thing `p` points to is const and cannot be written to by de-referencing `p`.

```
int * const q = &x;
```

This assigns the address of `x` to the *const pointer to int* `q`. That means, the pointer is const and cannot be altered afterwards, you can however alter `x` by de-referencing `p`.